# Rx.Net: how to read all files simultaneously and on different threads

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Currently I am able to read the files in a folder in sequence one by one & one line at a time with below code using reactive C#.

Now I would like to read all the files simultaneously and on different threads to speed up the processing. How to achieve this using reactive extension C#.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Test\", "*.txt"))
        {
            File.ReadLines(file)
                .ToObservable()
                .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Parallel.ForEach`;

```
var fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Test\", "*.txt").ToList();
Parallel.ForEach(fileList, file =>
{
    File.ReadLines(file)
        .ToObservable()
        .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
});
```

Comment: `Task.CurrentId` @user584018

Comment: `.Subscribe(z => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", z, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));`

Comment: @Stormcloak, Is there a way that each line reading is proceed by different `thread`. The above code process each file on different `thread`. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It may cause read the lines out of order. I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Using X threads may not make reading the files faster. That will depend on whats the bottleneck in your system.

Old harddrives that are spindel based become much slower if drown them in read requests.

In simular senarios to this i have had 1 dedicated thread for that adds the content to a ConcurrentQueue, and you can them use multiple threads to parse.

Comment: thanks for into, can you please give some tutorial.code link?